# $.each append to existing element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append some new elements to an existing append in a for each, but it only shows on the page as [object], i am missing something?

```
    strObj = {"width":"12","id":"table_test","title":"Latest Indexed Pages","headers":[{"title":"Page Url"},{"title":"Country"},{"title":"Language"},{"title":"Status"}],"data":[[{"text":"/services","link":""}],[{"text":"/services","link":""}]]}

    $('<tbody>',{}).append(
        $.each(strObj.data,(function(i,ii){
            $('<tr>',{}).append('<td></td>')
        }))
    )
```

****ADDED****

I was trying to simplify my ask, my full code looks like this, and am just trying to create the code as one snippet to the actual page, as I get the JSON string passed into this function. after I create the TR, then i would loop through the data to add the TD's

```
    let tableCreate_structure = $('<div>',{class: 'cold-'+tableCreate_width,'id':strObj.id}).append(
     $('<div>',{class:'card'}).append(
      $('<div>',{class:'card-header'}).append(
       $('<h3>',{class:'card-title'}).text(strObj.title)
      ),
      $('<div>',{class:'table-responsive'}).append(
       $('<table>',{class:'table table-vcenter card-table table-striped'}).append(
        $('<thead>',{}).append(tableCreate_headers),
         $('<tbody>',{}).append(
          $.each(strObj.data,(function(i,ii){
           $('<tr>',{})
          }))
         )
        )
       )
      )
     ); 
   $('#content_body').append(tableCreate_structure);
```

**I have the {} in there cause there will be classes and id's added after.. just trying to nail this down first

Comment: Look more closely at your structure. It's not just key/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

As tadman mentioned, your `data` member is not a simple array or object, it's actually an array of arrays of objects.
You didn't specify how you want the `strObj` object to be laid out in the table.

Also your selectors shouldn't include the brackets, i.e. just write `$('tbody')` to select the tbody element.

The way you have nested the $.each() loop inside the append() call won't work because $.each() returns its first argument, not some result of the loop, see https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/#jQuery-each-array-callback

I suggest the following: Build your table as HTML string first and append the final thing at the very end. This avoids multiple browser re-renders at each append call (slow if table is big).

If you want to chain appends you could do it as $().append( content1, content2) or $().append(content1).append(content2) see https://api.jquery.com/append/#append-content-content

Assuming you want each data member to be laid out in a row you could write:

```js
var strObj = {
  "width": "12",
  "id": "table_test",
  "title": "Latest Indexed Pages",
  "headers": [{
    "title": "Page Url"
  }, {
    "title": "Country"
  }, {
    "title": "Language"
  }, {
    "title": "Status"
  }],
  "data": [
    [{
      "text": "/services",
      "link": "one"
    }],
    [{
      "text": "/services",
      "link": "two"
    }]
  ]
}

var row = "";   // build HTML string in row
for (var line = 0; line < strObj.data.length; line++) {
  row += "<tr>";  // open new table row
  $.each(strObj.data[line][0], function(key, val) {
    row += '<td>' + key + ": " + val + '</td>';
  });
  row += "</tr>"; // close the table row
}

// now append the HTML string to the table
$('tbody').append( row );
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid grey; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    The table:
    <table>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Run the code snipped to see what it looks like and modify as needed.